# Bootstrap class not working fot Window.print

Tags: angular

bootstrap class is not applying when i do Window.print(). Hidden-print class is not working . I include bootstrap link to index.html but still its not working.please suggest me what else i can do to make it work

Comment: Add to angular.Json:  "styles": [
"styles.css",
"../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
],

Comment: I tried your solution but its not working

Answer (score 0):

This [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ijwjr7) should help.

working for:

- Bootstrap4: **d-print-none**
- Bootstrap3: **hidden-print**